# ngChange event fired twice when using multi-select with crmUiSelect

Tags: developer, angular, select2

I'm trying to use CiviCRM's `crmUiSelect` AngularJS directive to create a select2 element in a form. I want to call a function in my controller when the user changes this element, so I'm using the `ngChange` directive. But each change is firing *two* calls to this function.

Here's a screenshot of the element, with the console logging below, after I've made one selection.

[image: screenshot]

This is my controller code:

```
$scope.options = [
  {"value": "foo", "label": "Foo"},
  {"value": "bar", "label": "Bar"},
  {"value": "baz", "label": "Baz"},
  {"value": "bat", "label": "Bat"}
];

$scope.log = function (value) {
  console.log(value);
};
```

and my template code:

```
<select
  crm-ui-select="{allowClear: true}"
  ng-model="myVar"
  ng-change="log(myVar)"
  multiple="multiple"
  class="big"
>
  <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}">
    {{option.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

How can I get the event to fire once instead of twice?

Somewhat frustratingly, the event *is* fired only once if I remove `multiple="multiple"` or if I remove the `crm-ui-select` directive. But I really do want a select2 *mtuli*-select here.